# Pop-up windows in R & Emacs

Tags: r, emacs, ess

I am using ESS in order to stay in Emacs when working with R. Whenever I create a plot a new pop-up appears with the graph. This new window seems to be a part of the R process called inside Emacs. As such the new window is not part of the buffer-list and seems to lie outside the Emacs environment.

Can a new window created by R, containing e.g. graphs called by plot() or respective functions in ggplot2/lattice, be forced to stay inside the Emacs environment? So that the plot is available as a new buffer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, sorry, it cannot. Emacs buffers are text. Graphics windows are graphics devices.

But you can do this yourself.  Before plotting, or even at the begin of a session, say

```
pdf(file="/tmp/myplotfile.pdf")
```

and now plots will go there.  You can then open the pdf file in Emacs, and recent versions include a pdf preview inside Emacs (at least on my Linux boxen, not sure if I needed extra modes for that).  That would come close to your requirements.

Comment: ok, that would be an idea. but then i have to call 'dev.off()' every time i called a plotting function and start a new 'pdf()' function before i create a new plot or update the old one.

Comment: You can add several plots to the same file, see `help(pdf)` and the `onefile` option.  But you may need to call `dev.off()` to synchronise / flush the file buffer.  But that may be the price you have to pay for what a somewhat uncommon usage pattern.

Comment: I am using the DocView mode in Emacs when loading the pdf. An automatic update does not work that smoothly, so when i call 'plot()' twice, the buffer with the pdf notes an error. only after calling 'dev.off' the buffer gets updated and i see the two plots. hmm....ok, then i guess i stay with the usual setting. but thanks dirk for the informations.

Comment: You could also use png(...) so Emacs doesn't have to use Ghostscript to convert PDF to PNG.  Unfortunately auto-revert-mode seems to not work properly at all though a regular `M-x revert-buffer` does.

Answer (score 9):

Oh yes it can...

In ESS, do this:

```
png(file="tmp.png")
plot(1:10)
dev.off()
# [[tmp.png]]
```

Nothing. Now do ESC X iimage-mode (yes, two i's there).

This puts your buffer into iimage minor mode, it should spot the [[tmp.png]] and load your image in there. This should be easily automatable. This is the first time I've discovered this for myself so there's probably better ways to do it.

There's clearly been some chatter on the ESS list about this:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/ess-help/2009-August/005474.html

but I am surprised its not in the ESS core yet...

Comment: Well that is more or less the same as my earlier answer, and not what OP asked for. He wants an emacs buffer as a native R graphics device. Which one would have to code.

Comment: Hmm ah yes, as a new buffer... Sadly I don't think you can write a graphics driver in pure R at the moment, which would make doing this a lot easier...

Comment: http://www.omegahat.org/RGraphicsDevice/overview.html i seem to be full of wrong today...

Answer (score 2):

This is unlikely to be the solution you are looking for as it involves turning Emacs into a window manager (works for Linux and MacOS): the package [EXWM](https://github.com/ch11ng/exwm) (Emacs X Window Manager) is a full-featured tiling window manager that turns **all** X windows into Emacs buffers.

Here is an example of what that would look like (note the R Graphics window on the right which is now an Emacs buffer):

[image]

This allows you to use Emacs keybindings, configuration, etc. to all X windows.

Comment: This is great. Can you please provide more details on how you set this up to work properly after installing exwm?

Answer (score 2):

This does not exactly answer the OP's question because this goes outside of ESS but it still may be relevant to some because it still relates to using R to generate graphics that can be viewed inside of Emacs.

You can do this using [Emacs iPython Notebook](https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook/wiki/Screenshots) (ein). You have to set up [Jupyter](http://jupyter.org/) first but after that it's pretty straightforward and can work with different kernels (R, Python, Julia, etc.). Below is a screenshot

[image: Screenshot of R plot in ein]

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
X11()   #  starts a X11 graphics device
plot(c(1:10),c(1:10))
savePlot(filename = "try_save_X11.png",type = c("png"))
```